# cgimagecreate set bytesperrow correctly but intensity of dots different as the image size changed

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage

I have the function below to create and return UIImage from CGImage.
imageBytes is type of UInt8 array containing 0 or 255, because in this case I want to display gray scale random dots.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithBitmapBytes:(Byte *)imageBytes width:(size_t)width height:(size_t)height componentCount:(NSUInteger)componentCount {
    // bitmap size
    NSUInteger imageBufferSize = width * height * componentCount;
    // CGDataProvider create
    CGDataProviderRef dataProviderRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, imageBytes, imageBufferSize, bufferFree);
    // 8bit
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    // 24 if RGB 32 if RGBA
    NSUInteger bitsPerPixel = bitsPerComponent * componentCount;
    // bytes per row
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = width * bitsPerPixel / 8;
    // CGImage 
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageRetain(CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNone, dataProviderRef, nil, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault));

    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProviderRef);

    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return image;
}
```

And I create two bitmap data(for outer image and inner image) with this function

```
- (void)setupBitmapArrays {
    bitmapImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    insideBitmapImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME; i++) {
        imageBytesArray[i] = calloc(imageViewWidth * imageViewHeight * componentCount, sizeof(UInt8));
        for (int j = 0; j < imageViewWidth * imageViewHeight; j++) {
             imageBytesArray[i][j] = random();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME; i++) {
        insideImageBytesArray[i] = calloc(insideImageViewWidth * insideImageViewHeight * componentCount, sizeof(UInt8));
        for (int j = 0; j < insideImageViewWidth * insideImageViewHeight; j++) {
            insideImageBytesArray[i][j] = random();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: random dot images outer and inner created by the functions above]

The image above contains outer and inner images(Left and right each).

The outer and inner image is overlaped but I set inner image's background color to white, so there is no overlap of dots themselves.But as you can see the intensity of dots are different, even though the bytesperrow parameter to image size ratio are the same. How can this happen?

Comment: The brightness/intensity of both the inner and outer image seem to be the same. The main difference I recognize is that the outer image either fits the screen resolution or the image pixels are bigger than the screen's resolution. Therefore, you get the full range of brightness from white to black. In the inner image however, the image pixels are most likely smaller than the screen resolution. Therefore, each screen pixel is an average of serveral image pixels. The averaging leads a smaller range of brightness between light and dark gray.

Comment: Thank you @Codo, do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All the problem was from the bitmap data I assigned to the inner image. I was assigning the bitmap data for outer image to the inner image.